# How to overwrite ngbdatepicker element style in angular6

Tags: angular

I have the code as below with input
how to overwrite the element style left to -166px so that calender do not hide last columns

How to change the element
style for ngbdatepicker datepicker

I am using ng-bootstrap datepicker and having issue that the right side is cutting of, it could be because of the nested div classes getting applied but I don't want to investigate each and every nested div class to figure it out, rather I want to overwrite the ng-datepicker property (left :-166px) which I figured out thru chrome dev tools i need to adjust left px

Comment: There must be a parent element with `position: relative; overflow: hidden`

Comment: Any other ways to style the ngbdatepicker alignment.   Using ngStyle directive or inline styling options

Comment: You could use a better ng-bootstrap library which uses the [CDK Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) like [this one](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) ([demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/basic/datepicker) / [code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/datepicker))